# Two divs having same class name and ID but at different component of the page. If I try to clear one input the other div input is also cleared

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    $('.clear-icon').click(function(){
      $('input').val('');
     })


<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="input-outer">
        <input type="text">
        <button class="clear-icon">X</button>
    </div>
    <div id="input-outer">
        <input type="text">
        <button class="clear-icon">X</button>
    </div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

I am trying to clear one value alone but both the values are getting deleted. How can I control it by clearing only the input field of which button is clicked

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-id

Comment: @Teemu here html is rendered from CMS and they have same input field across multiple pages, so we don't have control of adding ids to input field

Comment: I would drop such a CMS when it creates invalid HTML.

Comment: The `id` must be unique as said in MDN website, if not then the input should have `name` attribute and must be unique so that JavaScript selector can be work to specific input. If there are nothing unique you may clear using something like `siblings` but you may found another problem in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `siblings`

```
$('.clear-icon').click(function(){
      $(this).siblings('input').val('');
     })
```

```js
$('.clear-icon').click(function(){
      $(this).siblings('input').val('');
     })
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="input-outer">
        <input type="text">
        <button class="clear-icon">X</button>
    </div>
    <div id="input-outer">
        <input type="text">
        <button class="clear-icon">X</button>
    </div>
```